# How to change the centre point of MKAnnotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I am using MKMapkit for map-section in my app.
I have to display a pin image [image] as MKAnnotation. When I add the annotation in map view, the center of the image, points to the latitude and longitude. But I want that the bottom-left corner of the image should point to the specified latitude and longitude.
I am following the link [MapCallouts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html) for displaying the annotation.
Is there any way to achieve the target.
Then please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set appropriate value to [centerOffset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207-CH1-SW19) property of annotation view:

> **centerOffset**
>
> By default, the center point of an annotation view is placed at the
>   coordinate point of the associated annotation. You can use this
>   property to reposition the annotation view as needed. This x and y
>   offset values are measured in pixels. Positive offset values move the
>   annotation view down and to the right, while negative values move it
>   up and to the left.